# How to remove white lines when viewing on iOS, Safari and Chrome?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, mobile-website, mobile-webkit

This fairly simple webpage has all kinds of issues loading and viewing on iOS, Safari and Chrome.

http://wsgdev.com/laceyoak/test.html

1. Sometimes the iPad/iPhone browser only displays one or two images when you refresh.
2. White lines are displayed above and below some images and not others. I have tried several fixes to this issue I found on Stack Overflow but none have worked.

Thanks so much in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I see those white lines and I'm not on iOS. So it's probably not an iOS specific issue.

Comment: me as well - on OS X - id guess.. maybe retina related somehow?

Comment: different white lines in safari and firefox but white lines in any case

Comment: id edit the question and the tags

Comment: I've been told the lines show up on iOS, Safari and Chrome but I don't see them in Firefox or Explorer.

Comment: So it's not specifically an iOS problem. 

It's such a simple page with only some rollovers. The only thing I did different than other sites I've created is I made the images width 100% so it will expand depending on screen size.

I'm lost as to why the white lines appear on certain browsers as well as why the page reloads different when you refresh on an iPad.

Wizards please help! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your images has different proportions when scaling in table layout. If you will added

```
td {
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

you will see that all white lines are on the bottom and it's a free space of every table cell. It's a feature of table render. Because height of any table cell is affected by the table cell with maximum height. So you are wrong on using table layout. Use `div`s, for example.